# Should I destroy Textures loaded from resources?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I create a texture with a `Texture2D.Create()` method, I should call `UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(...)` method for it to prevent memory leaks.

But should I call `Destroy` method for textures, loaded with `Resources.Load<Texture2D>(...)` method? Or it is automatically destroyed with `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets()` call or something?

Answer (score 0):

When you load textures using Resources.Load(...) in Unity, the engine automatically handles memory management for the objects loaded through Resources.

In this case, it is not necessary to call Object.Destroy(...) for textures loaded using Resources.Load.

Comment: And how does engine determine if texture still used or not?